# ASP.NET ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest not working?

Tags: asp.net, system.web.ui.webcontrols

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest appears to be doing nothing.  What am I missing?

For example, despite the fact that CompleteRequest is called during every interesting event, all of the below events still run on a simple test page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace LifeCycle
{
    public partial class _Default_NoMasterPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private int count = 0;

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            nextLabel("InitBeforeBase");
            base.OnInit(e);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            nextLabel("Init");
        }

        protected override void OnInitComplete(EventArgs e)
        {
            nextLabel("InitCompleteBeforeBase");
            base.OnInitComplete(e);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            nextLabel("InitComplete");
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            nextLabel("OnLoadBeforeBase");
            base.OnLoad(e);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            nextLabel("OnLoad");
        }

        protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
        {
            nextLabel("OnLoadCompleteBeforeBase");
            base.OnLoadComplete(e);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            nextLabel("OnLoadComplete");
        }

        protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            // can't add a control to the page during OnPreInit as the other page control doesn't exist yet.
            base.OnPreInit(e);
        }

        private void nextLabel(string eventName)
        {
            string lbl = "" + ++count + " " + eventName + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "";
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl c = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            c.InnerText = lbl;
            Page.Controls.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it turns out I had a fundamental misunderstanding of completerequest.  CompleteRequest skips the rest of the IIS HTTP pipeline chain, but the ASP.NET page handler event lifecycle finishes running because it is just one part of the HTTP pipeline chain and nothing has told this part to stop.

Comment: Believe I resorted to Response.End()